# java how do you open a shortcut next to the program?

Tags: java, load, exe

Hi im trying to run/open a shortcut from the folder next to my jar file.I can't seem to get it to work it as it keeps saying

> The system cannot find the file specified

Can you please point out to me what am doing wrong?

```
JButton btnInstall = new JButton("Install/Run");
    btnInstall.setEnabled(false);
    btnInstall.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            ChangePath(ProgramAdder.programs.get(count).ProgramPath.toString());
            System.out.print(ProgramAdder.programs.get(count).ProgramPath.toString());
        }
    });
    btnInstall.setBounds(173, 226, 116, 45);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnInstall);

public void ChangePath(String Path){
    try {
        Process process= Runtime.getRuntime().exec(Path);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

.

```
package Logic;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ProgramAdder {
public static List<Programs> programs = new ArrayList<Programs>( );

public static void ProgramList(){
    ProgramAdder.addProgram("HD Sentinel","/Shortcuts In Order/1 - HDSentinel.lnk");
    ProgramAdder.addProgram("Defraggler","/Shortcuts In Order/2 - Defraggler.lnk");
    ProgramAdder.addProgram("CC Cleaner","/Shortcuts In Order/3 - CCCLEANER.lnk");
    ProgramAdder.addProgram("Hit Man Pro 64Bit","/Shortcuts In Order/4 - HitManPro 32bit.lnk");
    ProgramAdder.addProgram("Hit Man Pro 32Bit","/Shortcuts In Order/4 - HitManPro 64bit.lnk");
    ProgramAdder.addProgram("Super Anti Spyware","/Shortcuts In Order/5 - SuperAntiSpyware.lnk");
    ProgramAdder.addProgram("Malware Bytes","/Shortcuts In Order/6 - MalwareBytes.lnk");
}
public static void addProgram(String ProgramName,String ProgramPath){
    Programs p = new Programs();
    p.ProgramName = ProgramName;
    p.ProgramPath = ProgramPath;
    programs.add(p);
}

}
```

I tried running this function in main but again i still get the same error

```
   package Logic;

import java.io.IOException;

public class OpenTets {
    public static void OpenProgram(){
        try {
            Process process= Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/Shortcuts In Order/1 - HDSentinel.lnk");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: (1) Fix your code blocks (click [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/34086463/edit)). (2) Don't `setBounds`, use a `LayoutManager`. (3) You are passing into `exec(Path);` what seems to be a class, but is probably an ill-defined variable (which you don't show us). (4) You are using classes like `ProgramAdder` which we have no idea what they are. I suggest you write a class out of scratch that just reads the file you are looking for and see if that works.

Comment: Path is a string that is passed in from this ChangePath(ProgramAdder.programs.get(count).ProgramPath.toString());

Comment: ProgramAdder is just a class that creates the list of the programs names and paths

Comment: That addresses (3) and part of (4). Now do what i suggested so you can solve your problem.

Comment: Hi i created a small class that tries to open one of the files but i still get the same error im sure im just typing the address wrong but am not sure the standard way to do it

Comment: Good. Then edit that class into your question. Also post what the string of the address looks like and also where the file is located in the file system. It appears to be a problem with the format of the relative path.

Comment: The files are located next to the executable jar file inside a folder called Shortcuts In Order. when i print the string files to the console they appear as they are typed

Comment: O.K., what you need to understand is that the `exec` argument is a command, not just a path. Do you actually need the `Process` object returned? If not, then you can use the simpler `Desktop.getDesktop().open` instead.

Comment: all i need is for the program to open ill try that and see if it changes anythng. ill also try using the full path name aswell

Comment: Thanks for your help that Desktop.getDesktop works perfect in my test class if you want you can post it as an answer and ill accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't need to keep the returned `Process` object from `Runtime.exec` then you can use the simpler [`Desktop.getDesktop().open`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#open-java.io.File-). Supply it with the `File` you want to open.